# Let $G = (\Bbb Z/18\Bbb Z, +)$ be a cyclic group of order $18$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm currently taking abstract algebra and I'm very lost.

> Let $G = (\Bbb Z/18\Bbb Z, +)$ be a cyclic group of order $18$.
>
> (1) Find a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $|H|= 3.$
>
> (2) What are the elements of $G/H$?
>
> (3) Find a familiar group that is isomorphic to $G/H$.

For one I think I understand that since it is a cyclic group we need a generator so I choose $\langle [6]\rangle$.  $[6]+[6]=[12]$ and $[6]+[6]+[6]=[18]=[0]$ so $H=\langle [6]\rangle=\{[0],[6],[12]\}$.  Here we see $18$ divided by $6$ is $3$ so $|H| = 3.$

The next part are the elements $G/H$ just the subgroup I wrote down before?

The last question is confusing me the most.  In order to be isomorphic to one another the group that I select must have three elements as well, correct?  The problem is there is no other subgroup of $G$ that has an order $3$.

Comment: No, $18$ divided by $3$, and not by $6$. So $G/H$ has $6$ cosets. Write down all cosets. So $0+[6]$,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G/H$ has 6 elements since $|G/H| =|G|/|H|=\frac{18}{3}=6$. We we are looking for a group with 6 elements. We say that $x,y \in G$ are in the same equivalence class if $x-y  \in H$, ie $x-y=0,6$ or $12$, so:

$0=6=12$

$1 = 7 = 13$

$2=8=14$

$3=9=15$

$4=10=16$

$5=11=17$

Therefore, the elements of $G/H=\{\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3},\bar{4},\bar{5}\}$.

Comment: I did the problem wrong then since |H|=3 so H=<[3]> correct?  Which would mean <[3]>={[0],[3],[6],[9],[12],[15]} So 18 divided by 6 is 3 hence |H|=3.  Now based on what your saying here x-y=0,3,6,9,12 or 15 but I can see more than 3 ways we can get this am I seeing this right?

Comment: Now I'm actually confused intitally I thought I was right but the comment in the question is confusing me

Comment: No! $H$ has 3 elements, but $<3>$ has 6 elements! Your initial $H$ was correct.

Comment: Okay this means my intital work on the problem is right, correct?

Comment: You answered part a correctly. Not part b. $H$ and $G/H$ are usually not the same.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For the last question, you can use the *third isomorphism theorem*:

$g=\mathbf Z/18\mathbf Z$, $H==6\mathbf Z/18 \mathbf Z$, so 
$$G/H=\mathbf Z/18\mathbf Z\Big/6\mathbf Z/18\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here $\lvert G/H\rvert=\lvert G\rvert/\lvert H\rvert=18/3=6$.

Also, $G\cong\langle a\mid a^{18}\rangle,$ so 
$$\begin{align}
G/H&\cong\langle b\mid b^{18/3}\rangle \\ 
&\cong \langle b\mid b^6\rangle \\
&\cong \Bbb Z_6.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't think you should use group presentations when the op clearly is a beginner.

Comment: That's a fair comment, @ThorWittich. Thank you. If you work with presentations as often as I do, though, everything looks like a nail for that particular hammer.

Comment: I am also fond of presentations, but many people are not (as I once again realized while teaching algebraic topology today haha).

Comment: Is there a more simple way to show this or would this be the best way to show it?

Comment: There's definitely a more simple way, @user710744. This is *a* way to do it; I'm not sure about the best though.

Comment: Bernard's answer seems to me more elegant than the others so far, @user710744.